# What year did "Wolverine: Origin" happen in?

Tags: marvel, comics, wolverine

I am talking about the comic *Wolverine: Origin*. I am quite confused on when the story takes place. It looks like 1700s to 1800s but I am almost 100% sure he is not over 200 years old.

Comment: That comic series spans Wolverine's entire life, if memory serves. Can you be more specific about which (of the 40 comics that make up this run) you're referring to?

Comment: @Valorum Maybe OP's talking about "Wolverine: Origin" limited series (without the last 's'), that according to wikipedia, as quoted by Paulie_D, takes place in the late-19th-century. I haven't read that series, I don't know if that date is explicitly mentioned there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The story spans a number of years between 1897 and 1907.

It's established in the opening scene of *[Wolverine: The Origin #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wolverine:_The_Origin_Vol_1_1)* that the story begins after the death of Wolverine's older, maternal half-brother, [John Howlett Jr.](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/John_Howlett,_Jr._(Earth-616)).

> MR: KENNETH: That there building is the Howlett Estate. They say it was built on a foundation of tears. Aye...a right terrible tragedy it was -- **just after the place was built, the elder boy took ill all of a sudden an' died. They buried 'im here on the grounds.** That was such a desperate sad day for everyone.
>
> [image: Wolverine: The Origin #1, page 2.]
>
> <sub>*Wolverine: The Origin #1* (November, 2001)</sub>

*[Wolverine: The Origin #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wolverine:_The_Origin_Vol_1_2)* shows John Jr.'s headstone, which specifies his year of death as 1897, so the opening scene of the first issue cannot be set before that year.

> JOHN
> HOWLETT
> BELOVED SON
> LOST BEFORE
> HIS TIME
> **1885-1897**
>
> [image: Wolverine: The Origin #2, page 8.]
>
> <sub>*Wolverine: The Origin #2* (December, 2001)</sub>

According to the [Marvel.com solicit](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/47454/origin_ii_2013_1) for *[Origin II #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Origin_II_Vol_1_1)*, it picks up a few years after the events of *[Wolverine: The Origin](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Wolverine:_The_Origin_Vol_1)*.

> Part 1 of 5! **A few years after the events of ORIGIN** finds James Howlett running with the wolves?until something unexpected brings him back into the world of Follow the first ""X-Man"" as he finds his way back to civilization and falls afoul of someone Sinister, who's just discovering mutantkind and the horrors he can visit on them. Plus, discover the secret behind James' greatest enemy! At some point, the mutant who will become The Wolverine must choose: is he man or is he beast? An all-new chapter in the secret origin of one of Marvel's most mysterious characters is revealed starting this November, by superstars Kieron Gillen (YOUNG AVENGERS, IRON MAN) and Adam Kubert (AVENGERS, UNCANNY X-MEN, WOLVERINE)!

And the introductory blurb of *Origin II #1* indicates that it begins in 1907.

> **It was 1907.**
>
> It was the end of the age of the great Empires of Steam, the clock of mankind ticking towards dreadful war.
>
> The entirety of the civilized world knew it.
>
> The mistake of civilized man being to believe his world was the world entire.
>
> This is a story about how civilized man came to know of another world and the man who lived there.
>
> This is a story about that man, one called Logan, who had chosen to live far away from civilization and those who disturbed him.
>
> It is a story of wolves and bears.
>
> It is a story of animals.
>
> [image: Origin II #1, page 1.]
>
> <sub>*Origin II #1* (February, 2014)</sub>

Note that Wolverine was a young boy in the first issue of *Wolverine: The Origin* and a young man by the sixth and final issue. The two main supporting characters in the story -- [Rose O'Hara](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Rose_O%27Hara_(Earth-616)) and [Dog Logan](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dog_Logan_(Earth-616)) (Wolverine's paternal half-brother) -- similarly grew up from children to young adults in that timeframe, and Rose mentioned that she was 12 years old in the first issue. This suggests that the story likely began not much later than 1897 (perhaps in that very year) and ended not many years before 1907.

Wolverine's aging during that period also suggests he wasn't born long after John Jr., whose year of birth was specified as 1885 on his headstone. If we say, for the sake of argument, that Wolverine was born in 1885 -- the earliest year he could possibly have been born in, per *Wolverine: The Origin* -- that'd make him about 138 in a present day context.

Answer (score 4):

[*X-Men: Prelude to Schism #4*](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/38481/x-men_prelude_to_schism_2011_4) is set in the same continuity. It gives the year as 1891 and states that Logan is nine. Hence the events of *[Wolverine: The Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(comics))* must take place around the 1890s.

[image]

This also tallies with the [official Marvel.com tagline](https://web.archive.org/web/20110621053130/https://www.marvel.com/digital_comics/issue/1136/origin_2001_1) for the *Origin* comic, published in 2001.

> **A century ago,** two young boys grow up together. One is wealthy, one is destitute. One will be Wolverine!
>
> <sub><sup>[Marvel.com - Wolverine: The Origin #1](https://www.marvel.com/digital_comics/issue/1136/origin_2001_1)</sup></sub>